How to get parent text of select2 selection?
Hello… I have a select2 dropdown with grouped elements, like this:

These are countries with their cities.
At some point of the code, I am getting the selected city this way:

$(’#Ubicacion_CiudadId’).select2(‘data’)[0].text

How can I get the text of the parent (the country name)?
I am using select 4.0.13
Thanks

See if this fiddle help you.
